# how to edit required Fields to not required in opencart 1.5

Tags: opencart

Higuys , when registering some required fields are not obligatoire ,
so how to edit required Fields to not required in opencart 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to `controller->account` directory, then
2. open `register.php`, then
3. go to function `validate`, then
4. change validation according to your requirement.